# ¿Como hacer que un button cambie su imagen al ser clickeado?

Tags: java, android, appinventor

¿cómo puedo hacer que un botón (button) hecho con Swing cambie de imagen al ser presionado? ¿o cuando pasen el mouse por encima del botón?

Ejemplo:

Botón normal: ========
 Botón siendo presionado: =-=-=-=

Es un ejemplo un poco tonto, pero supongo que me entienden

Gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un **[selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html?hl=es-419)** definiendo imágenes para ambos estados, al ser presionado y normal:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btnOn"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btnOff"/>
</selector>
```

Este selector lo guardas dentro del folder `/drawable`  y lo mandas llamar en tu `ImageButton` por medio de la propiedad `android:src`:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/image_selector" 
... 
/>
```

---

Otra opción es cambiar la imagen al pulsar el `ImageButton`, por ejemplo suponiendo tener 2 imágenes dentro de `/drawable` llamadas btnOff.png y btnOn.png, al detectar si el boton esta pulsado o no, determinamos cambiar las imágenes mediante :

```
imageButton.setImageResource()
```

Ejemplo:

```
        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btnOff);
                    return true;
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btnOn);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplicación donde se muestran ambas opciones:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-ImageButton-switch-images/wiki

Comment: Probaré con la segunda opción, muchas gracias :)

Comment: @SinXeros agregué un link con una aplicación la cual realiza las 2 opciones. saludos. Recuerda marcar como correcta si la respuesta soluciona tu pregunta. saludos.